# How to create single button Dialog in android?

Tags: button, dialog

I have been searching for days trying to figure out how to add dialog with single button in my application. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dialog is simple, or is the question how to determine if a update is nessecary?
Here the Dialogbuilder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FisMapView.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Update required");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                     
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            } 
                        });

                        builder.setNeutralButton("Abort", null);
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
```

edit:
I can't figure out how to check for updates in the market, i would suggest to compare the version with a website of your own, if you increase the versionnumber on this site, call the market to download the newest version or download the apk externally

Answer (score 0):

Store the current version in your apps defaultsharedpreferences. Have a variable on your main activity which you increment when you increment the version in the manifest. During run, have it check the current with the version in the code and do something if the new one is higher. Then update the one in the preferences.

EDIT:

If they hit cancel on the dialog, have the program end so they are forced to see it every time they open it until they run the update.

Comment: In you main activity, you have an int currentVersion; You increment it everytime you put an update on the market. You store a previousVersion in your preferences. In onCreate(), you check the previousVersion from preferences and the currentVersion from the code and compare them. If currentVersion > previousVersion, you run the code which make the changes and update the preference so previousVersion equals currentVersion.