# How do you create an update dialog in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Update Dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471499/how-to-create-update-dialog-in-android)

I've been searching for day trying to figure out how to create an update dialog which notifies the users that I have a new updates. What I really what is, whenever I have a new update on the market, I want some dialog to pop up on their application only when I have update. Please help me, it would be really mean a lot to me. Thanks in advance!

I want to create something like this[image]