# Update dialog controlled by remote server in android?

Tags: android, dialog

Basically, I want to create an application, and when this application has update, I want some dialog to show up only when I have updates. Moreover, this updates are controlled by remote server. How can I accomplish this? Can someone give me some simple example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean Market updates to your application code, or some sort of updates in your app's content (eg unread articles, message notifications?)

Comment: I need to notify the users that I have a new updates so they can go to market and download the new one

Comment: In that case, this sure looks like a duplicate of [How to create Update Dialog in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471499/how-to-create-update-dialog-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean actually update the dialog on the screen of your application? Only the parent, which would be your application can update the UI. So the remote server wouldn't be able to update the dialog remotely. You can, however, periodically check the status of the remote server from your application and update that way.